# How to handle unexpected result in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Sorry I am new with EF. May be I need some understanding.

I have a store procedure sy `[sp_location_get_by_zip]`.
If zip code matches in table then returned columns are:

```
[Loc_id], [Location_name], [Lat], [Long], [Zip_code]
```

but if zip code does not match the returned column is:

```
[Error] (zip code not found)
```

This was easily handled with reader. in try catch I was checking if `[Error]` column does not exist then read other columns other wise just send this DB message(zip code not found) to UI.

Now how this is handled in entity framework?

I am still using stored procedure and this is DB first project.

Answer (score 1):

EF expects you to either return a single (possibly empty) result set, or throw an error.  So you should change the behavior, or use a wrapper stored procedure to give EF what it expects.

David

Comment: I got 4.5 years experience and I am not sure if this good or lack in EF but no other option. Thanks for response